# How to combine the output of Stanford English Parser with that of Graphene

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Graphene is an information extraction pipeline which extracts Knowledge Graphs from texts (n-ary relations and rhetorical structures extracted from complex factoid discourse). Given a sentence or a text, Graphene outputs a semantic representation of the text which is a labeled directed graph (a knowledge graph). This knowledge graph can be later used for addressing different AI tasks, such as building Question Answering systems, extracting structured data from text, supporting semantic inference, among other tasks. Differently from existing open relation extraction tools, which focus on the main relation expressed in a sentence, Graphene aims at maximizing the extraction of contextual relations.

Link for Graphene (http://lambda3.org/Graphene/ ).
Can the parser performance be improved by combining the outputs of Stanford English Parser with that of Graphene?If yes then how?